# How to sort the columns of a row in dataframe based on value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:
[image]

I want to sort the value on `2015/11/30`.
I want the sorted dataframe to be like:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? You mean sort by index in ascending or descending order?

Comment: Is it dataframe with index ts?

Comment: ascending order. Thank you.

Comment: This is quite a poor question, a quick search would show [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), please check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#reshaping-sorting-transposing) first

Comment: Sorry, I the beginner.last_sector_pct_change.sort_index( ascending=False) can'twork.

Comment: Basically, what are you expecting as output?

Comment: If you'd read this question yourself, given that there is no input data, code to create the df, and no explanation of what the desired output should be and a statement *can't work*, would you understand the question? then please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post the mandatory data to help others help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many comments and questions it looks you want to call [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
In [25]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,5))
df

Out[25]:
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.489902 -0.283736  0.145133  0.554305  1.386065
1 -0.019177  0.166250 -0.610949  1.421608 -1.123981
2 -0.613483 -0.629143 -0.877431  0.558777 -0.021781

In [31]:
df.iloc[-1].sort_values(ascending=False)

Out[31]:
3    0.558777
4   -0.021781
0   -0.613483
1   -0.629143
2   -0.877431
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

You can use the index values to index the columns:

```
In [32]:
df[df.iloc[-1].sort_values(ascending=False).index]

Out[32]:
          3         4         0         1         2
0  0.554305  1.386065  0.489902 -0.283736  0.145133
1  1.421608 -1.123981 -0.019177  0.166250 -0.610949
2  0.558777 -0.021781 -0.613483 -0.629143 -0.877431
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort columns of a rowike below,

```
df
Out[98]: 
               open    high      low
date                                
2015/11/26  9861.48  8484.9  4656.74
2015/11/27  9841.48  8384.9  4256.74

df.loc['2015/11/26'].order(ascending=False)
Out[99]: 
open    9861.48
high    8484.90
low     4656.74
Name: 2015/11/26, dtype: float64

df.loc['2015/11/26'].order(ascending=True)
Out[100]: 
low     4656.74
high    8484.90
open    9861.48
Name: 2015/11/26, dtype: float64
```